# Is it possible make in Vegas Pro?

Tags: video, video-editor, animation, vegas-pro, presentation

I need to create a brief presentation of my mobile app. I use Vegas Pro. But I have weak skills. I want to do something like this: the text and the animated image are interchanged.

I would like to make something like this:

It is possible make with Vegas Pro? Or is it better to use another application?
any advice and suggestions - there is already no time :)

Comment: That video was probably made with After Effects, which is pretty popular for this kind of things. There are also a lot of template you can download/buy if you have no experience with that

Comment: It's totally possible: the best way to achieve a professional look is, suprisingly enough, to hire a professional.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but animations are much better suited for a speciality program like After Effects. Vegas on its own will only provide you basic video effects and nothing close to animations like these.